# How to hide the navigation bar in Android - corona , lua

Tags: lua, navigation, coronasdk

I saw some ways to do hide the navigation bar but they don't work for me. I don't understand how to do that and where I need to write the code. I saw this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id)
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN)
```

and also this:

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
```

but I don't know where to write this codes and I also need a code for hiding it for all the time. for example: like in the game "Jelly Jump".

Comment: are you using corona or Native android?. The above code is for the native android.

Comment: I am using corona, sorry. so you have a Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have founed it. This code worked for me:

```
if ( system.getInfo("platformName") == "Android" ) then
   local androidVersion = string.sub( system.getInfo( "platformVersion" ), 1, 3)
   if( androidVersion and tonumber(androidVersion) >= 4.4 ) then
     native.setProperty( "androidSystemUiVisibility", "immersiveSticky" )
     --native.setProperty( "androidSystemUiVisibility", "lowProfile" )
   elseif( androidVersion ) then
     native.setProperty( "androidSystemUiVisibility", "lowProfile" )
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the navigation bar use,

```
native.setProperty( key, value )
```

But it has some restrictions, have a look at this to know more http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/native/setProperty.html#androidSystemUiVisibility

Comment: your answare is amazing! but i have a question: why does you the only one to know that? I searched a lot and no one knew that. it is a new option?

Comment: I tried to use it and it doesnt work. I tryed it like that: native.setProperty("androidSystemUIVisibility", "immersiveSticky") or: native.setProperty("androidSystemUIVisibility", immersiveSticky) and nothing hapens. The navigation bar is still there. what do I do wronge?

Comment: have a look at this , http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/44626-is-it-possible-to-hide-the-android-navigation-bar-the-one-with-the-home-and-back-buttons-in-corona-sdk/

Comment: from this forum - Rob Miracle: "Ah.... This was added to daily build 2398, the first daily build after the last public release.  The forums say you are a Starter account, so this is not a feature in the SDK you can use."
someone can tell me what he means? (I am Newbie)

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide status and navigation bars:

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar);
native.setProperty("androidSystemUiVisibility", "immersiveSticky");
```

In case Android's version is < 4.4 (KitKat), at least status bar will be hidden. There are other tags you can use. The full description can be found on my [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/userful-things-about-corona-sdk/#header).